# Convert Varchar To Money

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, money-format

I am trying to convert a `varchar` column to money but I keep getting this error

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to money is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Am I not using the convert function like the error suggests?

```
Select
    tellerID,
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN CONVERT(money, value1) IS NULL THEN '0' 
           ELSE CONVERT(money, value1) 
        END) AS [Total Value 1]
From 
    intakedrawer
Group By 
    tellerID
Order By 
    tellerID
```

Comment: Man, I hope my bank doesn't store my balance as a varchar...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Select
tellerID,
SUM(CASE WHEN IsNumeric(value1) = 0 THEN 0 
       ELSE CAST(value1 AS decimal(18, 2)) 
END) as [Total Value 1]
From intakedrawer
Group By tellerID
Order By tellerID
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on SQL Server 2012 or higher you can also use [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx). If the conversion doesn't work it returns NULL.

```
SELECT
 tellerid,
 SUM(TRY_CONVERT(MONEY, value1)) AS [Total Value 1]
FROM intakedrawer
GROUP BY tellerid
ORDER BY tellerid;
```

There's a SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b73c/1).

Comment: Sorry, I should have indicated that in my initial post, this is SQL 2008

Comment: No worries. In that case Rahul's answer is the one you want. Please be sure to mark it as accepted if it works for you :)